# Connecting lots of small Wi-Fi devices in a home without choking the router

Tags: wireless-networking

I would like to experiment some [domotics](http://future.wikia.com/wiki/Domotics) using Arduinos, Raspberry PIs et al.

I am no network expert. I surely know how routers, modem and switches work and I know the internals of various OSI protocols, but I'm a 100% ignorant on Wi-Fi.

Each device may control a light bulb, or the air conditioning system, or whatever. I would like to have all of them connected to the local network using Wi-Fi, so that I can control them using my PC or a smartphone.

All of these devices however would not need Internet access (99% of the time) and I do not want to connect all of them to the main home router, rapidly filling the 255 slots for the IPs. I am also worried about the speed issues that may come having tens of devices connected to a router build to support 4-5 connections.

What I am thinking at is a "sub-network" (correct term?) where all the devices are connected to a "master device", which would be an access point and run a DHCP server. And the master device would in turn be connected to the home network, allowing for internet access and remote control of the infrastructure.

Is this even possible? The master would have a Wi-Fi connection and an access point for other devices. Does it need two Wi-Fi adapters?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you describe is precisely why wifi is the least desirable wireless protocol for home automation (domotica).  There are many protocols competing for this space, e.g. Z-wave, ZigBee, Thread to name a few.  Best advice is to explore devices supporting these instead of wifi.  In addition to unloading your network they use less power which is a huge factor in small/portable/battery powered devices.

However, if you insist on using wifi you have two issues to address:

1. IP address space, which is easy enough (eg. use a 10.x.x.x/8 address space) and use a router or other DHCP server capable of handling that.
2. Quantity of Wifi devices talking at once to an access point.  The only real solution is multiples of access points (but means running more cables, managing wifi channels and planning for minimize RF overlap) or using a single more powerful multi-channel/stream access point (eg 3x3 or at LEAST 2x2)
   Good access points of this capability will NOT be cheap. I do home automation for a living and in cases where I have more than 50 wifi clients or expect more than 15 or so simultaneous or heavy use wifi clients I will use nothing less than a Ruckus R300 (msrp around $450 iirc).  Peers have recommended Aruba to me as well and comparable models price similarly.

As far as segmenting the network a good AP (like the R300) will provide you with multiple SSID (wifi broadcast names) and you can tag each ssid for as a different vlan.  This is much like differnet subnets but with less futzing around of static routes in the router.  This will require a multiport router or a Layer 3 switch though to handle the VLAN tags properly.

Bottom line - seriously reevaluate the use of wifi based devices if you'll have any substantial amount of them.  Overall you'll end up with a much better experience, probably spend less, have less headache and free up your wifi infrastructure for your computers and tablets which will make for better experience on them as well.

hth.

Answer (score 1):

Wi-Fi is like old Half-Duplex Ethernet.

Some routers lock Your LAN in 255.255.255.0 mask, but many allow to use other mask with much more that 254 addresses. 10.0.0.0/255.255.0.0 for example, give You 65534 IPs.

If You really get more that 200 wireless devices, You can get problem with wi-fi, because of collisions and AP overload. In this situation You need to plan Your Wireless coverage by many AP and different frequencies (channels 1, 6, 11). It depend on how huge your project is.

Separation of home automation in separate subnet (in L3/IP view) and separate broadcast domain (in L2 view) has usually more security that performance problem.

What You described is possible.
If You just put this devices on separate Wi-Fi channels, "master device" is one or more additional AP. 
If You make separation on L2 and L3 level, "master device" is more or less professional router (For example Mikrotik as I professional in it) and add static routes to your current router. It is possible, to use "home router with Wi-Fi" in this place, but because "home router" usually force using NAT, You must define many port-mapping rules for access from devices on main home net to devices in home automation net.

I expect You plan to add not more that 10 - 20 HA devices at once. Just add and monitor load on Your net. Look what problem You face at first.

If You plan to quickly and painlessly deploy thousands HA devices, you need hire consultant or anyway make step by step lab tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect all your devices to a separate access point (router) on a different channel that the rest of your home, but you may still run into the problem of having many devices associate with an access point designed for just a few.  You could always buy a more expensive AP if that is within your budget.

Connect the second AP to your primary router via a wired connection for best results.   Set your primary router to channel 1 and the device router to channel 11, for example.